# Tight layout for matplotlib 3d surface plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am trying to create a 3d surface plot in matplotlib. the plot surface works fine using ax.plot_surface api. But I couldn't find a way to remove the padding surrounding the subplot. In fact, I don't need the outer axes that go from 0.0 to 1.0 at all. How can i remove the padding? I already tried many suggestions from stackoverflow like "ax.autoscale_view('tight')" and "fig.tight_layout()". autoscale_view don't change anything and fig.tight_layout() is not available in the matplotlib version i am using. For strict compatibility requirements i have to use a very old (Version 0.99) version of matplotlib. Any ideas ?

For completeness I have added a sample source code i am using:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (18,12))
rect = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 2).get_position()
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect)
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.025)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.025)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.view_init(azim=-90, elev=90) 
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: 0.99 is from 2009 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v0.99.0 and according to gh there have been 12k commits to master since then.   In any case, can you provide a minimal example?  I am unclear on why you have an axes in an axes.

Comment: @tcaswell, sample code added, The outer axes seems to come from subplot. Is there a way to remove these axes in 0.99 version from the plot?